# Why do we prepend Shanu Raboseinu to the sixth Perek of Avos and not other Perakim appended from Braisos?

Tags: mishna, pirke-avot-ethicsof

The sixth Perek of Avos begins

> שנו רבותינו בלשון המשנה ברוך שבחר בהם ובמשנותם
>
> The Rabbis taught in the language of the Mishnah. Blessed is He Who chose them and their teachings.

[Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84860/9682) I ask why this particular formulation is used, but the idea is that it makes the point that this Perek is not actually from Mishnayos Avos, but rather a Braisa (in this case, Kallah and Seder Eliyahu Zuta).

Why is it only here? Take the fourth Perek of Bikkurim as an example, Perek Adreigonus. It’s not actually from Mishnayos Bikkurim, but rather added from the second Perek of Tosefta Bikkurim. I don’t see that Perek beginning with this notation. For a single-Mishnah example, take Pesachim 4:9; the Gemara on 56a only quotes 4:8 and brings down 4:9 as ”Tanu Rabbanan” (which introduces a Braisa). So why is Avos 6 the only one that gets this notation?

While one could argue that it’s because it’s recited publicly, the words of Rashi on the Mishnah would seem to indicate otherwise:

> **שָׁנוּ חֲכָמִים בִּלְשׁוֹן הַמִּשְׁנָה.** כְּלוֹמַר בְּרַיְתָא הִיא וּבִלְשׁוֹן הַמִּשְׁנָה הִיא שְׁנוּיָה, אֲבָל אֵינָהּ מִשְׁנָה. וּמַה שָּׁנוּ, רַבִּי מֵאִיר אוֹמֵר וְכוּ'. וּלְפִי שֶׁעַד עַכְשָׁיו כָּל הַפְּרָקִים מִשְׁנָה, לְפִיכָךְ הֻצְרַךְ לְהוֹדִיעַ שֶׁמִּכָּאן וְאֵילָךְ בְּרַיְתָא הִיא. וּמִתּוֹךְ שֶׁהַלָּלוּ דִּבְרֵי הַגָּדָה הֵן וּמְסַפְּרוֹת בְּעֵסֶק תַּלְמוּד תּוֹרָה נָהֲגוּ לְאָמְרָן בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת עִם שְׁאָר פְּרָקִים הַלָּלוּ שֶׁל מַסֶּכֶת אָבוֹת:
>
> That is to say, this is a Braisa, taught in the language of the Mishnah, but it’s not a Mishnah. What was taught? “R’ Meir said, etc.” Since up until now all these Perakim were Mishnah, therefore it’s needed to inform that from here on is Braisa. Since these are words of Aggadah and discuss learning Torah, the Minhag is to say them in shul with the other perakim of Avos.

To me the wording implies “These are Braisos, therefore it needs to specify that these are not Mishnayos. Why was this included? Because we learn it in shul.” Not “We include this because we learn it in shul, therefore we need to tell people that these are Braisos” - seemingly anyone reading this would need to know they’re Braisos, independent of the reason this Perek is included.

Comment: Some versions (Artscroll) have תניא at the beginning of Perek Androginus

Comment: @Heshy In Mishnayos even? Not just in the Gemara where it appears?

Comment: @DonielF yes.  this one http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578193547.html

Answer (score 1):

Midrash Shmuel

> שנו חכמים וכו'. כוונת זאת ההקדמה לשבח של הברייתות השנויות בפרק הזה כי אף שכל החמשה פרקים הקודמים הם משניות **גם אלה לחכמים וראוי להעריכם בערך משניות**, וז"ש שנו חכמים כי פירוש שנו חכמים כמו תנו רבנן דקאמר בגמרא אלא שהגמרא שהיא מסודרת בלשון תרגום אומרת תנו רבנן ובכאו שמדבר בלשון הקדש אמר שנו חכמים **והודיענו כי מעלת הברייתות כמעט שהוא שוה אל המשניות לא יחסר כל בהן** רק שהמשניות נשנו במדרשו של רבינו הקדוש והברייתות נשנו חוץ למדרשו ועל כן נקראו ברייתות לשון חוץ כי תרגום מחוץ מברא. וזה שאמר שנו חכמים בלשון המשנה **כלומר אלו הברייתות בלשון המשנה הם שנויות והם אמרו והם אמרו ועל כן ברוך האיש אשר בחר בהם ובמשנתם כי גם אלו ראוים הם ליקרא משניות כי שוים הם אל המשניות**: ‏

The message is that the quality of Braytot teaching is equivalent to the quality of Mishnayot. They are only different in name because they was taught out of the Bet Midrash of Rabbi. Why is it said in this masechet and not in berayta of Androginos? Possibly because in Avot the Mishna begins by transmission, the berayta begins by accreditation of itself as an entire part of the transmission.

Comment: And only these Braisos and no others meet this level of quality?

Comment: No, it's pointed here.

Comment: The midrash shmuel seems to say this

Comment: But, say, Bikkurim 4 doesn’t count? Why is that so less pointed?